# Is this a stupid way to handle session storage with PostgreSQL? Should I use GENERATED values?

Tags: postgresql, session, random, generated-columns

I'm making a login system for a small application - that is, there will not be many users. I figured I'd store sessions as 4-byte integers, as that'd be far more than enough.

My basic idea is this:

```
session_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (random() * 4294967295 - 2147483648)
```

Ie., the database creates a more or less random number, which is used as primary key, and identifier for the session.

Is there an obvious pitfall with this sort of approach? What happens if there's a collision? I'd imagine it tries again, but does it? And there should be no risk of the table filling up, but what'd happen if it were about to run out of unique numbers?

I also looked at definitions like `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` or `GENERATED ALWAYS AS(expression) STORED`, but I don't really want a sequence, and those seem to require immutable functions, and random() isn't apparently immutable. Is there a way to implement them with this sort of approach?

I did some preliminary testing and my basic idea seems to work. But I'm unsure if it's good on the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `session_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` - this strictly guarantees and enforces uniqueness. If someone attempts to `insert` the same `session_id` for the second time or `update...set` another one to introduce a duplicate, it'll get rejected with an error.
2. `Random()` with two constants only make uniqueness *likely*. Given enough time/attempts, it's therefore guaranteed to break.
3. Without adding `unique` or `primary key`, you're not enforcing it at all - nothing's watching out for collisions, nothing reports them, they are free to occur.
4. You can always run out of numbers, but with `bigint` and `uuid` there's a lot to run out of. Unless that's a seriously large project, other things will typically break sooner than you manage to exhaust them.
5. If you want non-sequential identity, use [`uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html):

   ```sql
   session_id uuid default gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY
   ```
6. If you're worried about identifiers being sequential, it might be because you're exposing them, which you shouldn't do even if they are not sequential.

Comment: plus 1 for uuid, imho the best way to create a session id

Comment: 1. Okay. But is BIGINT too big? Is it wasteful and inefficient to use it over INTEGER?

Comment: @Xutulu if you could fit under a smallint limit, even int is wasteful. These are all so tiny and fast compared to everything else that will drive your latencies, performance and resource consumption, that I wouldn't worry about it too much. All good answers on which one to choose depend on specifics of your size, scaling, traffic - if you want to be sure, you need to thoroughly analyze your requirements and constraints.

Comment: I pressed enter accidentally.

Thank you for your good insights. I have a couple of extra remarks:

1. Okay. But is BIGINT too big? Is it better than INT4 performance-wise?
2. Yeah, but it might be good enough anyway.
3. I do have it specified as primary key as a constraint, it was just excluded from here.
4. Yep.
5. This doesn't work with identity though; the one in your first point? And isn't uuid much less efficient, especially with indexes? Or that has changed recently?
6. Well, they're only being exposed to users who succesfully log in. I guess they could as well be sequential.

Comment: 1. "Too big" is relative. You need to know how many values it's supposed to fit to answer that. It's worse than `int` performance-wise, and `int` is worse than `smallint`. In certain scenarios, you can go down from `smallint` to `char(1)` or [`"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE). 2. "Good enough" is also relative. For what? For how long will this operate, how big should it be able to scale? Proven and reliable solutions will get you just as far as eyeballed good-enough's, and further.

Comment: 3. Please edit that in. Even if it was clarified later, a question needs to always provide the full context, without relying on comments for it. 4. Yup. 5. No it won't, `identity` clause handles *sequences*. `UUID` *is heavier* than `bigint`, but it's more unique, sparse and non-sequential by design. It's less efficient proportionally to its byte size. The native `uuid` type is actually a number, a longer one, so it indexes and searches exactly the same as numerics. Alphanumeric characters and dashes you see are just a text representation of the number. 6. Back to numeric identity column, then